# Collapsible Set content wont take jQuery Mobile style

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a little fiddle that I modified to demonstrate the problem I'm currently having  http://jsfiddle.net/TPxT7/. Basically I need the `textboxes` to have the nice `jQuery Mobile` style, but regardless of what I `refresh` or `trigger` nothing seems to change. The collapsibles are always going to be created dynamically.

I'll attach the codes in-case there is something wrong with the links:

HTML:

```
<div id="medListDiv" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="e" style="padding:10px;">

</div>
```

SCRIPT (Sorry about lack of indentation):

```
$(function() {
var key, value;
var Storage = 5
// loop through local storage
for (var i = 0; i < Storage; i++) {
// retrieve the key
key = i;
// set the field from the key
value = "Medicine" + i.toString();

//$("#medListDiv").show();
var text = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right">' + '<h2>' + value + '</h2>' + '<input type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />' + '<textarea cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Type any directions written on your prescription for the above medicine." ></textarea></div>';
 $("#medListDiv").append(text);
 }

 $('#medListDiv').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
//$('.ui-collapsible-set').collapsible("refresh");
//$("#medListDiv").trigger("create");
//$('.ui-collapsible-set').trigger("create");
});
```

As you can see at the bottom I have tried adding the following bits of codes (not all at once):

```
$('.ui-collapsible-set').collapsible("refresh");
$("#medListDiv").trigger("create");
$('.ui-collapsible-set').trigger("create");
```

and I have also tried to follow some of the answers give on [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955028/jquery-mobile-add-collapsible-content-inside-of-a-listview-li-dynamically) question but nothing seems to make any difference, maybe I'm missing something, but I can't seem to work my head around it.

To makes things more clear, I want it too look like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nF38/1/) I created in static mode.

Any suggestions or ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a silly thought and a quick look around other questions and answers I solved it by just adding the following:

```
$('#medListDiv').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
$('#medListDiv').collapsibleset("refresh"); //This did the trick
$('#medListDiv').trigger("create");
```

Thank you for reading/passing by :)

Comment: `.collapsibleset()` is enough to refresh all collapsibles within.

Comment: Yes :D I discovered that and would hardly ever forget now as I spent a while searching for it lol

Comment: Would it be inappropriate to ask you here why this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWxrD/) wont behave like this new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m5xUz/). I have "improved" upon my original question and I can't seem to know whats wrong. Please let me know if I should modify my question or create a new one, but any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: You're adding collapsibles to a collapsible, not a collapsible-set. check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/j8BSv/ I used `.trigger("create")` just to apply styles on collapsibles contents.

Comment: Yes thats what I wanted, to nest individual collapsibles into a collapsible :) I managed it! Here is what I meant http://jsfiddle.net/PTWtL/, apparently just needed to assign which div to append it into like `div:first` on `$("#medListDiv div:first").append(text);`. Thank you though! :D (I should really stop asking before trying a bit harder -_-) - Sorry :(

Comment: you mean `.ui-collapsible-content` div ;)